# How to include bootstrap and jquery in my Laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, package

I am making a package for Laravel 5 that will use bootstrap 3 and jquery. 
How to include these assets in my package properly? 
What if a person who will use my package will already have bootstrap and jquery in his/her project? Is it necessary to check that?
I can put them in my folder assets of the package, but what if these assets are in the project already?

Comment: if the files are same, then no need to include same file again or upload in folder. Try to include the files in main master blade so that that will be used in all blades.

Answer (score 2):

You can not check if the project already has these assets, but if you want to include your own as part of the package you can do so with a provider.

Make a provider and register it in `config/app.php` (if your package doesn't have one already) and inside the `boot()` method you can "publish" (copy) assets from your package folder into the *public* folder of the Laravel application.

```
$this->publishes( [
    realpath( base_path( 'your/package/folder/with/assets' ) ) => public_path( 'desired/folder/in/public' )
], 'public' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default files without any modifications. then it is better to use from online repository, As keeping it public may override users custom settings. and it is wise to keep the package as small as possible. 
 And also you cannot check the whole project of user for these files